# Enum type django and rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a problem with the rest framework and one enum field. I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coreapi/codecs/corejson.py", line 48, in decode_schema_from_corejson
    return schema_cls(title=title, description=description)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

when the model has this field:

```
class PuddleAtomStatus(ChoiceEnum):
    INVALID = "INVALID"
    OK = "OK"

class PuddleAtom(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    ingestion_flow = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    status = EnumChoiceField(enm_class=PuddleAtomStaus)
```

but anything is fine when

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I'm using  Django 1.11 and python 2.7

Is there a way to fix this and leave the model with the enum field ?

Comment: UPDATE: the problem is https://github.com/core-api/core-api/issues/47 do you have any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, I can say that this is as simple as DRF not knowing what this special EnumField is. So you'll probably have to write your own serializer.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/core-api/core-api/issues/47 this exactly the problem I have. Reading this post I got this link: https://github.com/core-api/python-client/issues/122 which talks about a workaround. Can you explain me how to use this workaround ? I'm newbie in python.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it this way :

```
class PuddleAtom(Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
                        ('INVALID', 'INVALID'),
                        ('OK', 'OK'),
                     )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    ingestion_flow = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

I hope this helps.
Here is the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve the problem, it raises the same problem I get using the enum field.  I found my problem is a bug about core-api https://github.com/core-api/core-api/issues/47, do you have any workaround ?

Comment: @ozw1z5rd okey, looking into it